# How to configure Content Builder 3 column layout in pixels instead of per cents?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, content-builder, standardlayout

I want to configure the standard Content Builder 3 columns layout in two columns, each equal to 99px and leave the middle column to expand in available space.
Like this:

```
  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#f5f5f5; border:1px solid #f5f5f5; table-layout:fixed;" class="layout-auto">
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top" width="99" class="resize-99">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:40px 0px;" class="reduce-pad-20"></td>
  <td align="center" valign="top" width="99" class="resize-99">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

But Content Builder have only one option - split column by per cent. Or maybe someone knows how to create a custom layout in Content Builder?